# A good approach for handling overriding multiple CSS backgrounds?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I love that CSS3 has introduced multiple background images... but the method of just having comma-separated images is kind of, well, not very cascading, if you know what I mean.

Is there *any* approach out there to take this:

```
.a {
   background: url(a.png) no-repeat center center;
}

.b {
   background: url(b.png) repeat-x 0 bottom;
}
```

And apply it to an element such as this:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Such that the computed style is:

```
background-image: url(a.png), url(b.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-position-x: center, 0;
background-position-y: center, bottom;
```

(I get that if the above CSS did this, it would be wrong. But it'd be great if there were a solution like a property `background-add` or something.)

I'm looking for any hope of a future solution to this... a spec, a solution that only works in some browsers, the use of jQuery, whatever... because there are a couple of other similar issues with the CSS3 spec as well. For instance, you can't separate out the properties of text-shadow, etc. It's rather frustrating.

Thanks....

Comment: As far as I know there's no way for this to be done. For now it would be easier to have two separate `div`s on top of one another with different backgrounds (if you wish to be able to edit each background on its own).

Comment: Add box-shadow to that list as well.

Comment: If you're just looking to cut down on the amount of CSS selectors you have to write and maintain, what about using a CSS preprocessor such as LESS or SASS?

Comment: I tried using invalid CSS, like background-add, background-add2, etc. properties, but unfortunately JavaScript can't parse invalid CSS properties because they're discarded.... I guess I may have to just use nested divs. A CSS preprocessor isn't really what I'm looking for, because I just wanted to use kube ( http://imperavi.com/kube/ )'s button styling but add icons to the buttons. It's a waste for the processed CSS to have all that gradient styling copied for every different icon.

Comment: I want to *cascade* the multiple backgrounds, i.e. I want the div to have both of the backgrounds. CSS3 supports multiple background images on the same element, but there's no cascading support, you just override the `background` declaration. I don't want to define `.a` and .`b` *and* `.a.b`, just like I don't want to say `h1 { font-size: 24px; } h1.blue { font-size: 24px; color: blue; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're going for... but it works without having to add extra elements to the HTML, and should give you some ideas to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/howlx5/VrWDk/

```
.a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/100/100');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.a * {
    position: relative;
}

.a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    content:"\0020";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: 0 0;
};
```